# How do i read already opened file in a another button click event directly .(i.e without open file dialogue in button click)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
        void OpenWithDialog()
        {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            ofd.Filter = "Triangle polygon file|*.poly";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                OpenPolyFile(ofd.FileName);
            }
        }

        void OpenPolyFile(string file)
        {
            var geometry = TriangleNet.IO.FileReader.ReadPolyFile(file);
            // ...
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

> How to read files in button1 click directly?

Comment: Copy paste same logic from other methods to `Button_click`?

Comment: what you want is that your geometry object be accessible in additional scopes besides OpenPolyFile(). So you can simply make the geometry declaration accessible to both methods, declaring it, say, in the form code behind

Comment: TriangleNet.Geometry.InputGeometry geometry = TriangleNet.IO.FileReader.ReadPolyFile("..\\..\\..\\Data\\superior.poly");

Comment: in this code iam trying to read one file at a time, instead of that what i need is that i select the files through open file dialogue and read it on button click without altering the code everytime.(superior.polyfile is a files name)

Answer (score 0):

what you want is that your geometry object be accessible in additional scopes besides OpenPolyFile(). So you can simply make the geometry declaration accessible to both methods, declaring it, say, in the form code behind

```
// class scoped variables
       [ThePolyFileType] (pick the right one here :) geometry = null;

        void OpenWithDialog()
        {
            var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            ofd.Filter = "Triangle polygon file|*.poly";

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                OpenPolyFile(ofd.FileName);
            }
        }

        void OpenPolyFile(string file)
        {
            geometry = TriangleNet.IO.FileReader.ReadPolyFile(file);
            // ...
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (geometry != null)
            {
              //do your stuff
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do i read already opened file in a another button click event
>   directly .(i.e without open file dialogue in button click)

I'm not quite sure why you want to read it twice, but if that requirement says, make *selected* `filename` available globally and use it.

```
private string filename;

void OpenWithDialog()
{
    var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    ofd.Filter = "Triangle polygon file|*.poly";

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        OpenPolyFile(ofd.FileName);
        filename = ofd.FileName
    }
}
```

Now you have opened filename available in `button_clcik` you can use this file and read again.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // now you can read the file.
    //File.ReadAllText(filename); //OR

     TriangleNet.IO.FileReader.ReadPolyFile(file); 
}
```